# Python How to use pointer in function

Tags: python

I have a simple question how can i send pointer of boolean varible with function?

example :

```
condition = True
def set_false(con):
    con = False
set_false (condition)
print(condition)
```

and i want to output is false.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
condition = True
def set_false(con):
    con = False
    return con
condition = set_false(condition)
print(condition)
```

OR

```
condition = True
def set_false():
    global condition
    condition = False
set_false()
print(condition)
```

Comment: global fix my problem. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @ÇağlarBingöl : welcome ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return`:

```
condition = True
def set_false(con):
   return False
condition = condset_false(condition)
print(condition)
```

Output:

```
False
```